# unwanted URL appended to redirection url

Tags: asp.net, url, redirect, exchange-server

We have a asp.net web application will send a confirmation email with redirection url to users email once they confirm the registration. But while sending the url, the url `"https://exchcas/owa/redir.aspx?C=cUl43mOPekKnIMaLWRr1yZSp78A6N9EIC9oVlRLrzMFpuM-1UucMKAHOqY5VYM297Nr6m36XwhM.&URL="` will be appended to our url.

for example,

our redirection url is `http://localhost:63554/Reg.aspx`

the url will be send some thing like below,

```
https://exchcas/owa/redir.aspx?C=cUl43mOPekKnIMaLWRr1yZSp78A6N9EIC9oVlRLrzMFpuM-1UucMKAHOqY5VYM297Nr6m36XwhM.&URL=http://localhost:63554/Reg.aspx.
```

Can anyone pls let me know why this append happening? and what is the meaning of this appened url?

Comment: Is it you sending the confirmation email, or Outlook? The `owa` in the url makes it seem like another app is doing this. If that's the case, you might better off asking this question on another StackExchange site, like SuperUser (I'm not too familiar with what other sites are availble, so there might be a better option then SU).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a standard Exchange behavior for security reasons. Available in Exchange 2003/2010 (not sure about 2013). In OWA email is located at .../username/inbox/message.eml. If user clicks on direct url such as `http://localhost:63554/Reg.aspx` then on that link you could read HTTP_REFERER value and obtain "/username/inbox/message.eml". So, the purpose of having redir.aspx is to avoid sharing a username and email subject as a part of HTTP_REFERER.

Read more here http://blogs.technet.com/b/exchange/archive/2004/07/26/197289.aspx

You can also take a look here http://blog.leederbyshire.com/2013/03/28/how-to-make-your-outlook-web-app-2010-redir-aspx-a-little-safer/

Comment: okay first. Can you please tell me how can we avoid this kind of outlook append?

Comment: It's a standard behavior for OWA, which cannot be changed. If you use Outlook you will not see such links. Is there any problem?

Comment: 1) Does it work when using Outlook? 2) Does the url work when typing directly in the browser?

Comment: no this is not working fine when typing directly in address bar. When we remove that url it is working fine. may i know how can we avoid this situation.

Comment: The reason why I asked about Outlook is that your site is using localhost which is accessible at the web server only. So, do your users use desktop Outlook and could they open the site when clicking on the link the Outlook? The other question would be - what is the error? Do you see the redir.aspx that tells that link is not accessible or your see some 404 or anything else?

Comment: 1) Actually this URL append is not happened locally. this is happened only in one of the case. For us it is sending url finely without the outlook url.so I just want to know in which kind of situations this kind of URL append will occur. 2) When entering the this outlook appended url in browser, it is showing page not found error. I just like to know in which kind of situation, this url will append. Can you please let me know this? it will helpful for me to find where the actual issue is.

Comment: 2) It is not clear which page is not found : a) https://exchcas/owa/redir.aspx b) http://localhost:63554/Reg.aspx

Comment: I mean when entire the entire url "https://exchcas/owa/redir.aspx?C=cUl43mOPekKnIMaLWRr1yZSp78A6N9EIC9oVlRLrzMFpuM-1UucMKAHOqY5VYM297Nr6m36XwhM.&URL=http://localhost:63554/Reg.aspx." in the browser, i'm getting page not found error

Comment: I understand about entire url. I need to know about redir.aspx. Please enter https://exchcas/owa/redir.aspx?c=&url=http://www.google.com and tell me its exact response (400, 404, owa error page with some text, etc).

Comment: I found the below error message while enter the above url in browser
"Firefox can't find the server at exchcas.

    Check the address for typing errors such as ww.example.com instead of www.example.com
    If you are unable to load any pages, check your computer's network connection.
    If your computer or network is protected by a firewall or proxy, make sure that Firefox is permitted to access the Web."

Comment: I suggest you to talk your Exchange administrator. He should know how the server is configured and why the link to OWA is not accessible from some of your machines. For me it means that this is not an issue in c#/asp.net but a problem in configuration on the mail server. Just send a test email with some URL from any other location, open that email from OWA and try to click on it.

Comment: So problem is in exchange server right. But i like to know in which case the exchange server url will appended with email confirmation  url. Do you have any idea on that?

Comment: It is not appended with email confirmation url. It's always added to all urls to all emails. Just send a test email with some URL from any other location, open that email from OWA and try to click on it.

Comment: ohh okay. I shall check this. thank you for your all informations and guidance. it helps me lot.

Comment: currently i dont have account in OWA. Can you please suggest some links for how to create account with exchange server?

Comment: youtube is not accessible from our network. Can you provide some link regarding the steps to create account with OWA based on screenshots?

Comment: do we able to avoid to add this exchange url with our original url? is there any settings for that?

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a [skip-owa-redir userscript](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/andersk/andersk-userscripts/master/skip-owa-redir.user.js) that replaces each indirect `redir.aspx` link with a direct link to the target URL, using `rel="noreferrer"` to address the privacy concern.